# How to I get data from tabulated data then print a message

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, amazon-cloudwatch, tabulate

I have below output after tabulating response from cloudwatch using get_metric_statistics. I would like to add validation that if any Sum is greater than 0 it will print a message saying there is an error. And if all Sum is equal to zero it will say no error.

```
> +| Timestamp              |   Sum | Unit   | |
> 2021-01-12T09:31:00+00:00 |     0 | Count  | |
> 2021-01-12T09:30:00+00:00 |     0 | Count  | |
> 2021-01-12T09:33:00+00:00 |     0 | Count  | |
> 2021-01-12T09:29:00+00:00 |     0 | Count  | |
> 2021-01-12T09:32:00+00:00 |     0 | Count  | |
> 2021-01-12T09:28:00+00:00 |     0 | Count  |
> +---------------------------+-------+--------+
```

Below is my python script

```
import json
import boto3
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from tabulate import tabulate

client = boto3.client("lambda")


class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return o.isoformat()

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)


client = boto3.client("cloudwatch")
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace="AWS/Lambda",
    MetricName="Errors",
    Dimensions=[{"Name": "FunctionName", "Value": "XXX"}],
    StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=360),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
    Period=60,
    Statistics=["Sum"],
)

message = json.dumps(response, cls=DateTimeEncoder)
message2 = json.loads(message)
message3 = message2["Datapoints"]
message4 = tabulate(message3, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql")
print(message4)
```

I know this seems easy but please help. Thanks!

Comment: Please click on links to see screenshots

Comment: Please include your code and output as code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @Maurice I edited the post. I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Add something like: `for message in message2: if message["Sum"] > 0: print("Some error") else: pass` so if you don't get a feedback, there's no error. In case some `Sum` is greater 0, it'll tell you `Some error`

Comment: @grumpyp That's correct, add it as an answer and you'll get an upvote ;-)

Comment: please mark my answer as solution if it works for you. thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add something like:

```
for message in message2:
   if message["Sum"] > 0:
      print("Some error occured")
   else:
      pass
```

so if you don't get a feedback, there's no error. In case some `Sum` is greater 0, it'll tell you `Some error`

Comment: Thanks @grumpyp but I am having this error when adding your code. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\geterrorV5.py", line 36, in <module>
    if message["Sum"] > 0:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: It worked when changing it to for message2 in message3:
   if message2["Sum"] > 0:
      print("Some error occured")
   else:
      pass

Comment: Is there a way to just print one line message? Like if any has sum greater than 0 it will print some error occurred? Because with the above code it prints multiple lines that Some error occurred depending on number of sum that is greater than 0.

Comment: Sure thats possible. You could add `error = True` after the `if message["Sum"] > 0:` statement. Then you could check this variable by `if error is True: print("Some error occured")`